# setstate doesnt set the state

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, setstate

set status of {fetchStatus: []) doesn't really make the fetchstatus array empty. when debugging in the for loop, the fetchStatus still have other valuees in the array.

```
this.setState({fetchStatus: []}, () => {
   for (const proxy of proxies) {  
      fetch(authUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: authBody  
      }).then((response) => {
          if (response.status !== 200){
            throw new Error(response.status);
          }
          return response;
        }).then((data) => {
          // expect fetchStatus to be empty array at the start of the first for loop
          fetchStatus.push("Fetched "+authUrl);
          // setting fetchStatus to ["Fetched"+authUrl}
          // when debugging at the first for loop, it's observed that fetchStatus is [otherArrItemsnotYetcleared, "Fetched"+authUrl)
          this.setState({fetchStatus});
       })
```

Comment: Can you provide the full code or what you expect to be happening? The code you shared appears to be working as expected?

Comment: added the comments inline in the code. It's not working as expected. Expect the fetchStatus array to be empty in the first line of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear in the example, but assuming `fetchStatus` is assigned *before* the `this.setState` it needs to be reassigned.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { fetchStatus: ["initial data"] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let fetchStatus = this.state.fetchStatus;

    console.log(fetchStatus); // ["initial data"]

    this.setState({ fetchStatus: [] }, () => {
      // fetchStatus is still referencing the initial array data.
      // The value in state has been updated so you need
      // to reassign to the new array value.
      console.log(fetchStatus); // ["initial data"]

      fetchStatus = this.state.fetchStatus;

      console.log(fetchStatus); // []

      this.setState({ fetchStatus: ["later data"] });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: inside for loop array, I would need to push the ['later data' into fetchStatus, not setting state =['later data']. after pushing, it still has data for ["initial data"].

Comment: Use `this.setState({ fetchStatus: this.state.fetchStatus.concat("later data");` instead. As @skovy already mentioned, the component might not be refreshing because the the state holds a reference to the inital array when you use `Array.push()`

Comment: I tried the above using concat but it still doesn't solve it, is it because my function is not at componentDidMount() method?

Answer (score 0):

`setState()` is async, so you should use it like this

```
//fetchStatus.push("Fetched "+authUrl);
//this.setState({fetchStatus});

this.setState({fetchStatus: this.state.fetchStatus.concat("Fetched "+authUrl)});
```